# Using local frameworks on Mac OS X

Tags: xcode, macos, frameworks

I'm developping an application for Mac with 3rd party frameworks. So I can not assume that these frameworks are installed. I deliver that frameworks with my app bundle and adjust the paths with install_name_tool.
This already works fine if the frameworks are not installed previously..
If the frameworks are installed I got an error message:

```
    Class *AClassINeed* is implemented in both
    /path/to/my/app/bundle/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/MyFramework.framework/Versions/A/MyFramework
    and
    /Library/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework/Versions/A/MyFramework.
    One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

How can I force my app to use the local framework? My app can run without installations, so setting an envrionment variable is not the way I can use.
Should I set some options in XCode?
Please note: I have to use relative paths because I can't be sure where my app runs.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I located the problem:
Everything works fine, but the framework loads some plugins which loads the framework from /Library/Frameworks folder - my app will crash
(I used "export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1" and run my app from terminal)

So my new question is: can I force my whole app to use the local framework? I don't know when the framework loads the plugins or how much, so it can be very anoying to use install_name_tool to adjust every single plugin...

Comment: Here is the solution: do it yourself on every file or use a tool which does it for you (maybe from the company that releases the framework)